# passing attributes in apache http client

Tags: java, ssl, curl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a curl like as shown below

```
curl -s -g https://example.com:8086 --tlsv1 --cacert /etc/myfolder/certificate.pem --cert /etc/myfolder/ssl/certificate.pem --key /etc/myfolder/com/certificate.pem
```

I have used apache java http client for accessing the above curl

```
 String url = "https://example.com:8086";
 HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
 HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
 httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 HttpResponse httpresponse = client.execute(httpGet);
 EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
```

but I don't know how  to pass certiifcates and attributes such as `-s` `-g` `--tlsv1` `--cacert /etc/myfolder/certificate.pem` `--cert /etc/myfolder/ssl/certificate.pem` `--key /etc/myfolder/com/certificate.pem`

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: You might need to use keystore and truststore: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablqw/index.html

Comment: @JiriTousek can you show me a sample example with java

Comment: can we do that using apache http client

Comment: @JiriTousek is keystore and pem different.....can you please give me some idea on this

Answer (score 0):

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadTrustMaterial(new File("/etc/myfolder/certificate.keystore"))
        .loadTrustMaterial(new File("/etc/myfolder/ssl/certificate.keystore"), "store password".toCharArray(), "key password".toCharArray())
        .build();
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslContext,
            new String[] {"TLSv1"},
            null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier()))
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://targethost/");
try (CloseableHttpResponse response1 = client.execute(httpGet)) {
    System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());
    EntityUtils.consume(response1.getEntity());
}
```

Please note depending on the format of your PEM files you will likely have to load them into a Java keystore first.